# Could not install mysql driver Erlang : src/mysql_auth.erl:178: crypto:sha/1 is deprecated and will be removed in in a future

Tags: mysql, erlang, erlang-driver

I ve been trying to install mysql driver using https://github.com/dizzyd/erlang-mysql-driver

```
==> mysql (compile)
compile: warnings being treated as errors
src/mysql_auth.erl:178: crypto:sha/1 is deprecated and will be removed in in a future release; use crypto:hash/2
src/mysql_auth.erl:179: crypto:sha/1 is deprecated and will be removed in in a future release; use crypto:hash/2
src/mysql_auth.erl:180: crypto:sha_final/1 is deprecated and will be removed in in a future release; use crypto:hash_final/2
src/mysql_auth.erl:181: crypto:sha_update/2 is deprecated and will be removed in in a future release; use crypto:hash_update/3
src/mysql_auth.erl:182: crypto:sha_init/0 is deprecated and will be removed in in a future release; use crypto:hash_init/1
src/mysql_auth.erl:182: crypto:sha_update/2 is deprecated and will be removed in in a future release; use crypto:hash_update/3
```

I am using Erlang 5.10.3. Any update for the driver to support Erlang 5.10.3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ths fork https://github.com/manastech/erlang-mysql-driver

Deprecated crypto functions removed in 84274b52f5